# Teradata 9804 Response Row Size or Constant Row size overflow error by using LPAD 3 times

Tags: sql, teradata

Below code is giving '9804 Response Row Size or Constant Row size overflow error' error after adding LPAD function. If I remove the LPAD function it running fine.

With ODBC ASCII Connection query is working fine with 2 LPAD Function. With 3 LPAD function its throwing error.

Can anyone suggest how to fix it.

```
SELECT 
 CAST(TableA.A AS VARCHAR(50)) AS A 
,LPAD(CAST(CAST(TableA.B AS DECIMAL(18,2) FORMAT '-9999999999999999.9(2)' ) AS VARCHAR(20)),20,' ') AS B
,LPAD(CAST(CAST(TableA.C AS DECIMAL(18,2) FORMAT '-9999999999999999.9(2)' ) AS VARCHAR(20)),20,' ') AS C
,CAST(CAST(TableA.D AS INTEGER FORMAT '9999999999') AS VARCHAR(10)) AS D
,CAST(CAST(TableA.E AS INTEGER FORMAT '9999999999') AS VARCHAR(10))  AS E
,CAST(CAST(TableA.F AS INTEGER FORMAT '9999999999') AS VARCHAR(10))  AS F
,CAST(CAST(TableA.G AS INTEGER FORMAT '9999999999') AS VARCHAR(10))  AS G
,CAST(CAST(TableA.H AS INTEGER FORMAT '9999999999') AS VARCHAR(10))  AS H
,LPAD(CAST(CAST(TableA.I AS DECIMAL(18,2) FORMAT '-9999999999999999.9(2)' ) AS VARCHAR(20)),20,' ') AS I
,CAST(CAST(TableA.J AS SMALLINT FORMAT '99999') AS VARCHAR(10)) AS J
,CAST(CAST(TableA.K AS SMALLINT FORMAT '99999') AS VARCHAR(10)) AS K

FROM TableA AS TableA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check the resulting data type of an LPAD, it's something like a VarChar(32000). When you got multile LPADs this exceeds the maximum row length of 64k.

You could add another typecast to reduce the calculated size:

```
,CAST(LPAD(CAST(CAST(TableA.B AS DECIMAL(18,2) FORMAT '-9999999999999999.9(2)' ) AS VARCHAR(20)),20,' ') AS VARCHAR(20)) AS B
```

The FORMAT specifies a leading space, but the CAST to VarChar removes it.
You can either switch to a Teradata style cast, which formats right aligned vs. left aligned for ANSI casts.

```
Cast(B AS DECIMAL(18,2) Format '-9999999999999999.9(2)' ) ( VARCHAR(20)) -- or better (CHAR(20))
```

or you simply switch to TO_CHAR:

```
To_Char(b, '09999999999999999.99')
```

Comment: I want a space in front of the number if the number is +ve. So, i am doing lapd.

Comment: @ITIB: Correct, it's the CAST which removes the leading space, see my edited answer.

Comment: I changed the code as (ColumnA) (FORMAT '-9999999999999999.9(2)') (VARCHAR(20)) and its working fine now. Thanks for you suggestion @dnoeth